# Can I use an input to add things to a POSTGRES TABLE? (Python)

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to transfer a user input from a python code to a table in postgresql

What I want to do is place an input() in this code and make it's value go to the comment (#) in the code.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="Twitterzuil",
    user="postgres",
    password="")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO Bericht2 (name) VALUES (#THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE INPUT TO GO)");
conn.commit()
```

I have no idea how, I'm really a beginner in all this so any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). Though i am sure this is for learning it is [not recommended](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/) to do it this way in general.

Comment: Would you mind giving a short example? I'm really a visual learner. Another way would be fine too, there's no obligation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking about is called string interpolation.  Using [f-style format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), this might look like

```
new_name = "'bob'"  # need single quotes for SQL strings

sql = f"INSERT INTO Bericht2 (name) VALUES ({new_name})" # => sql == "INSERT INTO Bericht2 (name) VALUES ('bob')"

cur.execute(sql)
```

Note the `f` at the start of the string, when you do this expressions inside `{}` pairs get replaced with their python values ([tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-f-strings-tutorial-how-to-use-f-strings-for-string-formatting/)).  There are also [string formatting approaches](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-string-interpolation-829e14e1fc75) involving `%` substitution and the `.format` method on strings.

If you are doing anything beyond the basics you should look into using the [SQLAlchemy package](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/); here's the link to their [insert api](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html).  Using SQLAlchemy will help reduce the [risks that can come with manually constructing SQL queries](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/).

Example from "[Inserting Rows with SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html)"

```
from sqlalchemy import insert
stmt = insert(user_table).values(name='spongebob', fullname="Spongebob Squarepants")

with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Legend. Thank you so much. Gonna get me through the rest much faster :)